# Zend db cascade delete multiple levels

Tags: zend-db, cascade

How does one make Zend Db cascade delete multiple levels of the hierarchy? For example:

dealers -> products -> attributes

deleting one dealer should go all the way down to attributes, and now it doesn't :(

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

On row of the Zend_Table_Abstract within the function `_cascadeDelete` a row is constructed like this:

```
$rowsAffected += $this->delete($where);
```

It should instead be constructed as something like this:

```
$toDelete = $this->fetchAll($where);  
foreach($toDelete as $row) {  
    $rowsAffected += $row->delete();  
}
```

More info [here](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-1103).
It's worked for me in one cause but need to test more.